# C++ library for parsing regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex

I need to validate some user input based on some predefined regular expressions. However I want to make things a little bit easy for the user, so I would like to generate a dialog with specific input controls based on the regular expression itself. So for example, given the following regular expression `Start position [0-9] End Position [0-9]` I would like to be able to generate a dialog with two combo boxes with numerical values. Is there any C++ library that I can use to parse the regular expression and determine what kind of input it needs so that I can dynamically generate the dialog and the controls ?

Comment: I don't know of any libraries that provide *only* this functionality, but most nicely implemented regex libraries will build a structural representation of the regex before applying it (often in a function called `compile`). If you find an open source regex library, you can rip this part out of it (if it's not external).

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, the C++ standard library has a regular expression library (`std::regex` in the `#include` file `<regex>`).

In order to extract values from a regular expression, you could use boost spirit. (see www.boost.org).

Comment: That won't do what they're asking for though. They want to parse the regular expressions themselves.